# How to read MKV bytes as video?

Tags: python, opencv, video-encoding, mkv

I am receiving fragment of MKV video in bytes. I need to take 1st frame of it for later processing without saving video in disk. For similar problem with image I use OpenCV or PIL and everything works fine, however, I am not able to do the same with video data. Any tips how to read video from bytes to memory object that I could use for later processing with OpenCV or some other library?

Comment: I'm also facing a issue in reading MKV files. I have raised a separate thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073859/read-a-bytes-image-from-amazon-kinesis-output-in-python).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I don't have your `bytes` buffer, I just created an MKV video file with `ffmpeg` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i SomeVideo.avi -f matroska -vcodec libx264 video.mkv
```

I then installed `imageio` with:

```
pip install imageio
```

Then I loaded the entire MKV video into memory so I have something that must look pretty much the same as the `bytes` object you receive stored in my variable `content`:

```
import imageio

# Get bytes of MKV video
with open('video.mkv', 'rb') as file: 
    content = file.read()
```

Now I should be set up and looking the same as you. Just for reference, the first few bytes of `content` look like this:

```
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#B\x86\x81\x01B\xf7\x81\x01'
```

So, let's continue.

```
# Wrap the content in a BytesIO and get an ffmpeg reader to read it 
vid = imageio.get_reader(BytesIO(content),  'ffmpeg')
```

I can now print the mean of each frame like this:

```
for num, image in enumerate(vid.iter_data()): 
    print(image.mean())
```

Or get the metadata and print it like this:

```
metadata = vid.get_meta_data()                                                             

print(metadata)

{'plugin': 'ffmpeg',
 'nframes': 750,
 'ffmpeg_version': '4.1 built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)',
 'fps': 25.0,
 'source_size': (1280, 720),
 'size': (1280, 720),
 'duration': 30.0}
```

**Keywords**: Python, video, frame, individual frame, FFmpeg, imageio, single frame, BytesIO, bytes, MKV, Matroska.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project and remember, questions (and answers) are free, so come back if you get stuck.

Comment: [matroska,webm @ 0x562fad8b1cc0] File ended prematurely
[matroska,webm @ 0x562fad8b1cc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none, 1280x720): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Comment: Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!

Comment: The above errors comes as I read an MKV bytes image imageio.get_reader(BytesIO(content),  'ffmpeg').
Or does this work only for video file

Comment: @Varun_Rathinam If you have a question, please just ask it in the normal way. It's free. You can click `share` under this question and add a link to your new one if you want to show the relationship between the two questions.

Comment: I have the question separately. Can you help this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073859/read-a-bytes-image-from-amazon-kinesis-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Mark Setchell got it right; though - in 2022 - you don't have to drop down all the way to `get_reader` anymore to do this.

**Setup:**

Create a test video:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -t 5 testsrc.mkv
```

create a MKV bytes string

```py
from pathlib import Path

mkv_bytes = Path("testsrc.mkv").read_bytes()
```

**Read the first frame:**

*ImageIO<2.15.0*

```py
import imageio as iio

req = iio.core.Request(mkv_bytes, "r")

# note: this is a bit of a hack, see
# https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/686
req._extension = ".mkv"

first_frame = iio.imread(req)
```

*ImageIO>2.15.0* (releases this week - W6 2022)

```py
import imageio as iio

first_frame = iio.v3.imread(mkv_bytes, format_hint=".mkv")
```