# Read only first frame from an MKV with Python

Tags: mkv, python-imageio

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972903/how-to-read-mkv-bytes-as-video/56977405#56977405) shows how to read MKV video using Python, but it appears to be reading/processing the entire video before the call to `imageio.get_reader` returns. Is there a way to parse just the first frame of the MKV using `imageio`? If not, how about another method?

Comment: Have you tried `iio.imread("my_video.mkv")`? [iio.imread docs](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/_core_29/imageio.imread.html#imageio.imread)

Comment: My understanding from the documentation is that that will read an image file and not the first frame from an MKV file

Comment: ImageIO is quite smart here. If you pass an MKV to imread, it will understand that the file is a video and treat it like other multi-image containers. It will forward the request to `imageio-FFMPEG`, extract the first frame, and return it as an image. You can get other frames too via `iio.imread("my_video.mkv", index=N)` or just extract all frames via `iio.mimread("my_video.mkv"` (returns a list of images/frames).